# Python, generate prime twins

Tags: python, sage

I tried to write a python program to generate the prime twins in sage.

However I can't quite seem to get it to work.

Code:
http://pastebin.com/PRnvJsf3

Sage is giving me the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    y = 1
  File "", line 1, in <module>

  File "/private/var/folders/6-/6-7wRVdAEhuqw8H28uS60U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp8b0dCT/___code___.py", line 19
    while s1[y] < s1[len(s1)]
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks i put in the missing colons.

Now i get

Traceback (most recent call last):    y = 1
  File "", line 1, in

File "/private/var/folders/6-/6-7wRVdAEhuqw8H28uS60U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmpEIEhQs/***code***.py", line 19
    if (s1[k] + s1[y]) == ((s1[k] + (s1[k] + _sage_const_2 )):
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Thanks, i also put in the missing parentheses

now i get

Traceback (most recent call last):    y = 1
  File "", line 1, in

File "/private/var/folders/6-/6-7wRVdAEhuqw8H28uS60U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp9RE23a/***code***.py", line 18, in 
    while s1[y] < s1[len(s1)]:
IndexError: list index out of range

Hmm, i suppose i cannot use len(s1) here.

Thanks so much, it is working now

while s1[y] < s1[len(s1) - 1]:

However,

s2 = s2 + s1[k] does not seem to be valid code.

I get the next error

Traceback (most recent call last):    y = 1
  File "", line 1, in

File "/private/var/folders/6-/6-7wRVdAEhuqw8H28uS60U+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp3tx5on/***code***.py", line 20, in 
    s2 = s2 + s1[k]
  File "element.pyx", line 1525, in sage.structure.element.RingElement.**add** (sage/structure/element.c:13476)
  File "coerce.pyx", line 797, in sage.structure.coerce.CoercionModel_cache_maps.bin_op (sage/structure/coerce.c:7678)
TypeError: unsupported operand parent(s) for '+': '' and 'Integer Ring'

THANKS SO MUCH

I found the last problem

I need to use, now it is working!

s2 = s2 + [s1[k]]

Answer (score 2):

You have unbalanced parentheses on the following line:

```
if (s1[k] + s1[y]) == ((s1[k] + (s1[k] + 2)):
```

I also noticed the use of `x.is_prime()`. I don't know if it's a Sage thing, but my standalone Python interpreter does not have an `int.is_prime()` method.

Finally, `s1[len(s1)]` will *always* raise an `IndexError` exception since `s1`'s indices run from zero to `len(s1)-1`.

Comment: x.is_prime() is working in sage, so i suppose it must be Sage thing.

Comment: Yes, and in fact Sage preparses `int` input to a Sage-specific class `Integer`, which does have this method.